# Примитив корзины с с покупками (интернет-магазин)

Tags: java, ооп, коллекции, java-hashmap

Я пишу примитивную корзинку с товарами. Наткнулся на проблему с удалением товара из корзины.
Вот мой код:

```java
public boolean remove(Products products) {
    if (products.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (basket.containsKey(products.getName())) {
        Products old = basket.get(products.getName());
        old.setAmount(products.getAmount() - 1);
        if (old.getAmount() != 0) {
            basket.replace(products.getName(), old);
            totalCost -= products.getCost();
        } else {
            basket.remove(products.getName(), products);
            products.setAmount(1);
            totalCost -= products.getCost();
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Код работает хорошо, единственное, если я пытаюсь удалить предыдущий добавленный элемент в корзину, я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой типа `ConcurrentModificationException`. Я посмотрел в интернете решения этой проблемы, там предлагается использовать iterator. Но так как я, очень мягко говоря, начинающий разработчик, я не понимаю, как это реализовать у себя.
Буду рад, если мне помогут!

Comment: исходя из указанного фрагмента кода, непонятно, что именно вы далете. добавьте класс целиком, а лучше еще и класс products, чтобы понимать, что вообще происходит

Comment: данная ошибка возникает когда вы пытаетесь удалить что-то из коллекции в том время, когда вы по ней итерируетесь. В данном участке кода, я итерации не вижу. Так что, как написали выше, нужен весь класс, или хотя бы тот кусок где происходит итерация